# Large capacity, SPI storage for PIC12f1840?

Tags: storage, pic, mpu

I'm using a **PIC12F1840** chip with an **MPU9250** accelerometer to collect movement data. I'm currently using a *1Kb*, **SPI RAM** chip, but it gets full quite quickly, and there is also data loss while trying to read the data from it (due to the RAM's need for continuous power!).
It doesn't have to be quick, the MPU's fastest speed is the only *184Hz*, and I'm planning to use it on a slower setting by default. Can someone suggest some type of memory?

Comment: If you don't have continuous power you need a EEPROM and not a RAM to hold your data.

Comment: Well, in ideal circumstances the power outage is only a fraction of a second!

Comment: You can try SPI F-RAM like: FM25CL64B-G

Comment: A `fraction of a second`is more than enough to lose data in a RAM!

Comment: Are you trying to make some kind of offline data logger with non-volatile memory? Like recording accelerometer values for maybe 1 day, then retrieve them back from a PC?

Comment: yes, but only recording for 10-20 minutes